# Powershell to export error "RPC unavailable" if machine unreachable onto the HTML report

Tags: html, powershell, batch-file

i have a PS script that gets the "C" drive on a multiple machines and export it onto an HTML report however when one of the machines is offline it shows error " the RPC unavailable" on the PS window itself.

i need the error to be exported with the output

```
SystemName  DeviceID    VolumeName
Server001   C:          OSDisk  50.0    18.2    False
Server002   offline     offline
```

The script I’m using is:

```
Function Get-ComInfo {  

param(  
## Computers  
$computers  

)  
#Here LOW Space thresold is less than 10% of the total size of the Volume 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DeviceID='C:'" -computer $computers | 
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},@{Name="LOW SPACE";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace / $_.size -lt .1)}} 

}  

Get-Content D:\CDrivereport\computernames.txt | ForEach-Object { Get-ComInfo -computers $_}  | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File D:\CDrivereport\CDrivereport3.htm
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`